# How to create a read-only flag that can only be used by an admin to actually flag nodes?

Tags: flags

Long story short, I installed [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) because [Best Answer](http://drupal.org/project/best_answer) was not working properly.  Is it possible to configure flags so that only the admin can flag something (aka an answer as being approved) but everyone can view the flag?

Answer (score 1):

Try setup Flag as "global flag" and then in "Flag access" setup "Roles that may use this flag" check-boxes only for Admin.

If in this case flag will not be shown for other users - you need create script that get flag value for each node and display this info.

```
$flag = flag_get_flag(FLAG_NAME);
$node->flag_value = $flag->get_count($node->nid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this, especially by using the not commonly known/used Rules Action "***Trim a flag***", which looks like so:

[image]

Here is a rule (in Rules export format) that you could use to trim a flag, say with machine name `best_answer`:

```
{ "rules_limit_access_to_best_answer_flag" : {
    "LABEL" : "Limit access to best answer flag",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_best_answer" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "flagging-user" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_trim" : {
          "flag" : "best_answer",
          "flagging_user" : [ "flagging_user" ],
          "cutoff_size" : "0",
          "trim_newest" : "1",
          "permission_check" : "1"
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Be aware: since you do not have the administrator role, your flagging-attempt has been ignored.",
          "type" : "warning"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you adapt `best_answer` to the machine name of the flag you're using, simply use the Rules UI to import the above rule in your own site (and enable the rule afterwards).

Some more details to explain the magic in the above rule:

- Rules Event = A node has been flagged (using the `best_answer` flag).
- Rules Condition = The flagging user does **not** have role "administrator".
- Rules Actions =

  - Trim the `best_answer` flag, with `cut_off` value equal to zero (which is the same as saying "*Ignore any flags from the flagging user*").
  - Set an appropriate warning message.

So with this approach, any user who has permission for the flag, will actually see the flag. But if they try to use the flag, it will be ignored unless they are an administrator.

Happy flagging with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)!